# Serializing/deserializing the children of a WPF canvas to/from a XAML file

Tags: wpf, xaml, serialization, canvas

I have a DragCanvas class which inherits from Canvas and provides functionality for drag&drop, resizing and repositioning of elements. I'd like to be able to save/load the contents of the canvas to/from a XAML file.

The export method looks like this:

```
public void ExportPanel()
    {
        string savedCanvasString = XamlWriter.Save(editCanvas);
        File.WriteAllText("Canvas.xaml", savedCanvasString);
    }
```

The code seems to be working fine, since I'm actually getting a Canvas.xaml file with a very long string.

However, the import method is throwing an exception in the XamlReader.Load method. More especifically: "Add value to dictionary of type 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary' threw an exception.". The code from the import method is partially based on [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590398.aspx). Here's the code:

```
public void ImportPanel()
    {
        string savedCanvasString = File.ReadAllText("Canvas.xaml");
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(savedCanvasString);
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
        DragCanvas savedCanvasChildren = (DragCanvas)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader); // The exception is being thrown here.

        // Assignment code should be here.
    }
```

Do you have any ideas of what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, I ended up serializing the relevant attributes myself. The contents of [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24681/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-4) were quite useful in the process of understanding how to approach the problem.